# comparing html values in html and jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need some help. i want to compare if html values are equal

I want to compare html select values. like i want to see how to compare html values

like i want to see if the selected values are equal

```
if ($("form select[name='cars']").val() == ("form select[name='colour']").val()) {
       #do things
        }

<form method="post">

<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="colour">
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="white">white</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare HTML values? What is the issue with provided code?

Comment: my problems is here `if ($("form select[name='cars']").val() == ("form select[name='colour']").val()) {
       #do things
        }` i just want to compere both select values

Comment: values of two these combobox are not equal !! how do you want to compare

Comment: Yes, you will never pass through your condition with your current values.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with ajax?

Comment: This question is not related to ajax , can you edit the heading of the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before comparing you need to make sure the value prop on the select tag are same in the two select blocks. here is an example code . hope it helps

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  if ($("select[name='cars']").val() == $("select[name='colour']").val()) {
    alert("values are equal");
  } else {
    alert("values are not equal");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="colour">
  <option value="volvo">black</option>
  <option value="saab">yellow</option>
  <option value="mercedes">red</option>
  <option value="audi">white</option>
</select>
<button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var cars = document.getElementsByName("cars")[0];

var colour = document.getElementsByName("colour")[0];

if(cars.options[cars.selectedIndex].value==colour.options[colour.selectedIndex].value)

{
//DO Something

}
```